# Use of unresolved identifier 'SecTrustEvaluateWithError' in ServerTrustPolicy.swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I install the pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7' on Xcode 9, swift 4 and I got this error - Use of unresolved identifier 'SecTrustEvaluateWithError' in ServerTrustPolicy.swift file

[here THE screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnPgy.png)

please tell me this version of alamofire is suitable for Xcode 9

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some Xcode version with iOS less than 12. Xcode 11 has iOS 12 platform.